# Confusion about presence channels associations with non presence channels in Pusher

Tags: pusher

Does creating a presence channel automatically show the presence info in the same named non-presence channel e.g.

"presence-chat" shows members of room "chat"

OR

Are these two channels completely un-associated and any associations between them must be maintained manually by the app?  And the presence channel is just a type of channel that can be arbitrarily named anything with the prefix "presence-"

So if it is the latter, then in a chat room use case one should subscribe the user to both the chat room channel as well as the presence of the chat room channel, which may or may not be named similarly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does creating a presence channel automatically show the presence info in the same named non-presence channel e.g.
>
> "presence-chat" shows members of room "chat"

No, `chat` is a public channel and doesn't not any presence type data or functionality.

> Are these two channels completely un-associated

Correct.

> and any associations between them must be maintained manually by the app?

Yes. But I'm not sure why you would want to use both a `chat` and `presence-chat` channel. All functionality available on a public channel (`chat`) is also available on a presence channel (`presence-chat`).

> And the presence channel is just a type of channel that can be arbitrarily named anything with the prefix "presence-"

Correct.

Information on channel types can be found via:
https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_channels#channel_types

> So if it is the latter, then in a chat room use case one should subscribe the user to both the chat room channel as well as the presence of the chat room channel, which may or may not be named similarly?

As above, presence channels offer all functionality of a public channel. So there's no need to use two channels where one can do everything.

Please let me know if I've missed a reason why you need two use two channel types. If so, I'll update my answer.

Comment: ok- so if I wanted to say send chat events as well - then I would just subscribe to the presence channel and I can send chat events to the presence channel.  I had assumed that presence channels only allowed presence events.  If that's the case - calling it something like presence-enabled channels might make it easier to understand.